How to replace ILMerge and ILMerge Task with another DLL merger in D365
I have been getting all sorts of issues with ILMerge and I decided to move away from it.
Too bad I could not get anything else to work.
The current project I'm working on is an assembly with external packages for Dynamics 365 workflows/actions.
I issue with it started when I tried adding Microsoft Graph package. And it doesn't seem like ILMerge lets it into the assembly.
I tried using LibZ and thought my case was Scenario 1, but I didn't get the result I was hoping for.
The way I found out I could use LibZ was to open NuGet package console, cd into my bin/Release folder and run:
libz inject-dll --assembly MyAssembly.dll --include *.dll --exclude MyAssembly.dll --move

This modified my assembly, but not in the way I was expecting.
Here's a comparison using ILSpy (you can install it with "winget install XP8C26VDWLP4T4"):
ILMerge:

LibZ

LibZ assembly does load using Plug-in Registration Tool but everything breaks and no workflow or works.
Am I using LibZ incorrectly, or maybe there is another way to merge assemblies so that it looks like the version that works?

Not an answer, but you may not need to merge your assemblies any more - have you looked into the plugin packages?

Do you mean not using a merger at all and publish with PRT? Are you saying that because something changed recently?

I think you might be referring to this hot news.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/build-and-package#dependent-assemblies

They don't support ILMerge, you can still use it though. My suggestion was more of a work around so you don't have to use ILMerge or LibZ or any other merge tool

For Dataverse the recommended approach now is using Plugin packages. However, this is not an option for On Premises installations. Also classic workflow activities are not supported here.
Luckily, for ILMerge a good alternative would be ILRepack.
Follow these steps:

Add a reference to NuGet package ILRepack.Lib.MSBuild.Task to your plugin project.
Add an XML file to your project named ILRepack.targets.
Set up the configuration in the XML.


Example

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="ILRepacker" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)" />
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)Another.Library.dll" />
      <InputAssemblies Include="$(OutputPath)Newtonsoft.Json.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ILRepack
        Parallel="true"
        Internalize="true"
        InternalizeExclude="@(DoNotInternalizeAssemblies)"
        InputAssemblies="@(InputAssemblies)"
        LibraryPath="$(OutputPath)"
        Wildcards="false"
        TargetKind="SameAsPrimaryAssembly"
        DebugInfo="true"
        KeyFile="$(SolutionDir)YourKey.snk"
        OutputFile="$(OutputPath)Merged\$(AssemblyName).dll"
        LogFile="$(OutputPath)Merged\ILRepack.log"
    />
  </Target>
</Project>

In the example above the merged dll will be created in the bin output folder under sub folder merged.
